# Execute php and html only under specified condition

Tags: php, jquery, html

So I have this piece of code that I am trying to work with. What I would like to do is to run the code only when `$formname == 4` and when it's not, I don't want the code to run. I tried using an *if statement* on the whole block of code but for some reason that did not work for me. I'm also pretty sure that there is a better way to write this code since all of my *if statements* have the same condition, so any suggestions on condensing the code would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to programming so pardon my lack of knowledge, and thanks in advance for any help.

```
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php if($formname == 4 AND $formID == null){ echo "style='display:none'" ;} ?>>
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/overview.php';  
    </div>
</div>

<?php $a++; ?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php if($formname == 4 AND $formID == null){ echo "style='display:none'" ;} ?>>
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/abroad.php'; 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $a++;?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php if($formname == 4 AND $formID == null){ echo "style='display:none'" ;} ?> >
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/safety.php';  
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $a++; ?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php if($formname == 4 AND $formID == null){ echo "style='display:block'" ;} ?>>
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/faqs.php';  
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share complete code and from where the variable $formname is coming ? Also tell me about $formID variable, that when it is NULL and when it is set? Also explain the relation between these two variables.

Comment: $formname depends on what link the user uses to get to the page, since there are multiple links for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look for something like this?

```
<?php if($formname == 4 AND $formID == null):?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>">
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/overview.php'; 
         ?> 
    </div>
</div>

<?php $a++; ?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" >
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/abroad.php'; 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $a++;?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" >
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/safety.php';  
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $a++; ?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>">
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/faqs.php';  
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$sty = "";

if($formname == 4 && $formID == null)
{ $sty = "style='display:none'"; }
?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php echo $sty; ?>>
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/overview.php';  
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $a++; ?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php echo $sty; ?>>
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/abroad.php'; 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php $a++;?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php echo $sty; ?>>
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/safety.php';  
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
$a++;
if($formname == 4 && $formID == null)
{ $sty = "style='display:block'"; }
?>
<div class="tabcontent2" id="tab_content_<?php echo $a; ?>" <?php echo $sty; ?>>
    <div class="tabs-content3">
        <?php 
            include 'Subpages/faqs.php';  
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that works too. There's less repetition with this one, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You Might had forgot the closing of PHP tag after:

```
 include 'Subpages/overview.php';
```

For display of the div you might use simple if else for example

```
<?php
       if(($formname == 4) && ($formID == null)){
      ?>
```

YOUR HTML TO DISPLAY

```
 <?php } ?>
```

Similarly you can display as many if conditions as you want.